# hi, I'm trying to get an id attributte but no luck, here is my code

Tags: javascript

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("fast");
var xx = elems.innerHTML.indexOf('full') > -1;
// alert("yes");
for (var i = 0; i < xx.length; i++) {
  var x = xx[0].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].getAttribute("id");

  alert(x);
}
```

```html
<tr class="fast">
  <div>full</div>
  <div>big</div>

  <span id="668"></span>


</tr>
<tr class="po">
  <div>xt</div>
  <div>ee</div>
  <span id="649"></span>


</tr>
```

there many elemnts with the same class but i only want to get the id of the class that contains "fast" and "big, any idea?"

Comment: 1. `elems` contains a collection of elements, not just one, so `elems.innerHTML` does not make sense. 2. `xx.length` also doesn't make sense, since `xx` would be a boolean, if the previous error is fixed.

Comment: Also you have invalid HTML; anything inside of a table-row should be wrapped within a `<td>` or `<th>`.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with the comments on this question, on top of that, the use case of this functionality is not clear. Nevertheless, here is my solution.

```html
    <table class="table">
      <tr class="fast">
        <td>full</td>
        <td>big</td>
        <td id="668"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="big">
        <td>xt</td>
        <td>ee</td>
        <td id="649"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

```js
    // get all elements with td tag
    const elems = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

    for (let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
      
      // select td with class big as parent  
      const big = elems[i].closest(".big");

      // select td with class big as parent     
      const fast = elems[i].closest(".fast");

      // get the id attributes
      if (elems[i].attributes.id && (fast || big)) {
        console.log(elems[i].attributes.id);
      }
    }
```

Sidenote:

- If you want your HTML tags to store data, use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) instead.